# Cant load layers from SQL Server in geoserver

Tags: javascript, .net, sql-server, openlayers, geoserver

I've tried to load a layer from sql server in geoserver but the layers doesnt load and the browser doesnt give any error.

My layer is created like this:

[image]

And when I try to preview my layer with openlayer in geoserver my layer doest load, and the box where is supposed see my layers remains white.

The "view-source" is:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/openlayers3/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
        .ol-zoom {
          top: 52px;
        }
        .ol-toggle-options {
          z-index: 1000;
          background: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
          border-radius: 4px;
          padding: 2px;
          position: absolute;
          left: 8px;
          top: 8px;
        }
        #updateFilterButton, #resetFilterButton {
          height: 22px;
          width: 22px;
          text-align: center;
          text-decoration: none !important;
          line-height: 22px;
          margin: 1px;
          font-family: 'Lucida Grande',Verdana,Geneva,Lucida,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
          font-weight: bold !important;
          background: rgba(0,60,136,0.5);
          color: white !important;
          padding: 2px;
        }
        .ol-toggle-options a {
          background: rgba(0,60,136,0.5);
          color: white;
          display: block;
          font-family: 'Lucida Grande',Verdana,Geneva,Lucida,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
          font-size: 19px;
          font-weight: bold;
          height: 22px;
          line-height: 11px;
          margin: 1px;
          padding: 0;
          text-align: center;
          text-decoration: none;
          width: 22px;
          border-radius: 2px;
        }
        .ol-toggle-options a:hover {
          color: #fff;
          text-decoration: none;
          background: rgba(0,60,136,0.7);
        }
        body {
            font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: small;
        }
        iframe {
            width: 100%;
            height: 250px;
            border: none;
        }
        /* Toolbar styles */
        #toolbar {
            position: relative;
            padding-bottom: 0.5em;
        }
        #toolbar ul {
            list-style: none;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        #toolbar ul li {
            float: left;
            padding-right: 1em;
            padding-bottom: 0.5em;
        }
        #toolbar ul li a {
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: smaller;
            vertical-align: middle;
            color: black;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        #toolbar ul li a:hover {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
        #toolbar ul li * {
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        #map {
            clear: both;
            position: relative;
            width: 486px;
            height: 768px;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
        #wrapper {
            width: 486px;
        }
        #location {
            float: right;
        }
        /* Styles used by the default GetFeatureInfo output, added to make IE happy */
        table.featureInfo, table.featureInfo td, table.featureInfo th {
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-size: 90%;
            padding: .2em .1em;
        }
        table.featureInfo th {
            padding: .2em .2em;
            font-weight: bold;
            background: #eee;
        }
        table.featureInfo td {
            background: #fff;
        }
        table.featureInfo tr.odd td {
            background: #eee;
        }
        table.featureInfo caption {
            text-align: left;
            font-size: 100%;
            font-weight: bold;
            padding: .2em .2em;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/openlayers3/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>OpenLayers map preview</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="toolbar" style="display: none;">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a>WMS version:</a>
          <select id="wmsVersionSelector" onchange="setWMSVersion(value)">
            <option value="1.1.1">1.1.1</option>
            <option value="1.3.0">1.3.0</option>
          </select>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a>Tiling:</a>
          <select id="tilingModeSelector" onchange="setTileMode(value)">
            <option value="untiled">Single tile</option>
            <option value="tiled">Tiled</option>
          </select>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a>Antialias:</a>
          <select id="antialiasSelector" onchange="setAntialiasMode(value)">
            <option value="full">Full</option>
            <option value="text">Text only</option>
            <option value="none">Disabled</option>
          </select>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a>Format:</a>
          <select id="imageFormatSelector" onchange="setImageFormat(value)">
            <option value="image/png">PNG 24bit</option>
            <option value="image/png8">PNG 8bit</option>
            <option value="image/gif">GIF</option>
            <option id="jpeg" value="image/jpeg">JPEG</option>
            <option id="jpeg-png" value="image/vnd.jpeg-png">JPEG-PNG</option>
          </select>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a>Styles:</a>
          <select id="imageFormatSelector" onchange="setStyle(value)">
            <option value="">Default</option>
               <option value="polygon">polygon</option>  
               <option value="giant_polygon">giant_polygon</option>  
               <option value="poly_landmarks">poly_landmarks</option>  
          </select>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a>Width/Height:</a>
          <select id="widthSelector" onchange="setWidth(value)">
             <!--
             These values come from a statistics of the viewable area given a certain screen area
             (but have been adapted a litte, simplified numbers, added some resolutions for wide screen)
             You can find them here: http://www.evolt.org/article/Real_World_Browser_Size_Stats_Part_II/20/2297/
             --><option value="auto">Auto</option>
                <option value="600">600</option>
                <option value="750">750</option>
                <option value="950">950</option>
                <option value="1000">1000</option>
                <option value="1200">1200</option>
                <option value="1400">1400</option>
                <option value="1600">1600</option>
                <option value="1900">1900</option>
            </select>
            <select id="heigthSelector" onchange="setHeight(value)">
                <option value="auto">Auto</option>
                <option value="300">300</option>
                <option value="400">400</option>
                <option value="500">500</option>
                <option value="600">600</option>
                <option value="700">700</option>
                <option value="800">800</option>
                <option value="900">900</option>
                <option value="1000">1000</option>
            </select>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a>Filter:</a>
              <select id="filterType">
                  <option value="cql">CQL</option>
                  <option value="ogc">OGC</option>
                  <option value="fid">FeatureID</option>
              </select>
              <input type="text" size="80" id="filter"/>
              <a id="updateFilterButton" href="#" onClick="updateFilter()" title="Apply filter">Apply</a>
              <a id="resetFilterButton" href="#" onClick="resetFilter()" title="Reset filter">Reset</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    <div id="map">
      <div class="ol-toggle-options ol-unselectable"><a title="Toggle options toolbar" onClick="toggleControlPanel()" href="#toggle">...</a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="location"></div>
        <div id="scale">
    </div>
    <div id="nodelist">
        <em>Click on the map to get feature info</em>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var pureCoverage = false;
      // if this is just a coverage or a group of them, disable a few items,
      // and default to jpeg format
      var format = 'image/png';
      var bounds = [-87.42916, 359.556877,
                    -16.767688, 470.99556];
      if (pureCoverage) {
        document.getElementById('antialiasSelector').disabled = true;
        document.getElementById('jpeg').selected = true;
        format = "image/jpeg";
      }

      var supportsFiltering = true;
      if (!supportsFiltering) {
        document.getElementById('filterType').disabled = true;
        document.getElementById('filter').disabled = true;
        document.getElementById('updateFilterButton').disabled = true;
        document.getElementById('resetFilterButton').disabled = true;
      }

      var mousePositionControl = new ol.control.MousePosition({
        className: 'custom-mouse-position',
        target: document.getElementById('location'),
        coordinateFormat: ol.coordinate.createStringXY(5),
        undefinedHTML: '&nbsp;'
      });
      var untiled = new ol.layer.Image({
        source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
          ratio: 1,
          url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/MNC/wms',
          params: {'FORMAT': format,
                   'VERSION': '1.1.1',  
                STYLES: '',
                LAYERS: 'MNC:LTE_130',
          }
        })
      });
      var tiled = new ol.layer.Tile({
        visible: false,
        source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
          url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/MNC/wms',
          params: {'FORMAT': format, 
                   'VERSION': '1.1.1',
                   tiled: true,
                STYLES: '',
                LAYERS: 'MNC:LTE_130',
             tilesOrigin: -87.42916 + "," + 359.556877
          }
        })
      });
      var projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
          code: 'EPSG:4326',
          units: 'degrees',
          axisOrientation: 'neu',
          global: true
      });
      var map = new ol.Map({
        controls: ol.control.defaults({
          attribution: false
        }).extend([mousePositionControl]),
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
          untiled,
          tiled
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
           projection: projection
        })
      });
      map.getView().on('change:resolution', function(evt) {
        var resolution = evt.target.get('resolution');
        var units = map.getView().getProjection().getUnits();
        var dpi = 25.4 / 0.28;
        var mpu = ol.proj.METERS_PER_UNIT[units];
        var scale = resolution * mpu * 39.37 * dpi;
        if (scale >= 9500 && scale <= 950000) {
          scale = Math.round(scale / 1000) + "K";
        } else if (scale >= 950000) {
          scale = Math.round(scale / 1000000) + "M";
        } else {
          scale = Math.round(scale);
        }
        document.getElementById('scale').innerHTML = "Scale = 1 : " + scale;
      });
      map.getView().fit(bounds, map.getSize());
      map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
        document.getElementById('nodelist').innerHTML = "Loading... please wait...";
        var view = map.getView();
        var viewResolution = view.getResolution();
        var source = untiled.get('visible') ? untiled.getSource() : tiled.getSource();
        var url = source.getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
          evt.coordinate, viewResolution, view.getProjection(),
          {'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html', 'FEATURE_COUNT': 50});
        if (url) {
          document.getElementById('nodelist').innerHTML = '<iframe seamless src="' + url + '"></iframe>';
        }
      });

      // sets the chosen WMS version
      function setWMSVersion(wmsVersion) {
        map.getLayers().forEach(function(lyr) {
          lyr.getSource().updateParams({'VERSION': wmsVersion});
        });
        if(wmsVersion == "1.3.0") {
            origin = bounds[1] + ',' + bounds[0];
        } else {
            origin = bounds[0] + ',' + bounds[1];
        }
        tiled.getSource().updateParams({'tilesOrigin': origin});
      }

      // Tiling mode, can be 'tiled' or 'untiled'
      function setTileMode(tilingMode) {
        if (tilingMode == 'tiled') {
          untiled.set('visible', false);
          tiled.set('visible', true);
        } else {
          tiled.set('visible', false);
          untiled.set('visible', true);
        }
      }

      function setAntialiasMode(mode) {
        map.getLayers().forEach(function(lyr) {
          lyr.getSource().updateParams({'FORMAT_OPTIONS': 'antialias:' + mode});
        });
      }

      // changes the current tile format
      function setImageFormat(mime) {
        map.getLayers().forEach(function(lyr) {
          lyr.getSource().updateParams({'FORMAT': mime});
        });
      }

      function setStyle(style){
        map.getLayers().forEach(function(lyr) {
          lyr.getSource().updateParams({'STYLES': style});
        });
      }

      function setWidth(size){
        var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
        var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');

        if (size == "auto") {
          // reset back to the default value
          mapDiv.style.width = null;
          wrapper.style.width = null;
        }
        else {
          mapDiv.style.width = size + "px";
          wrapper.style.width = size + "px";
        }
        // notify OL that we changed the size of the map div
        map.updateSize();
      }

      function setHeight(size){
        var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
        if (size == "auto") {
          // reset back to the default value
          mapDiv.style.height = null;
        }
        else {
          mapDiv.style.height = size + "px";
        }
        // notify OL that we changed the size of the map div
        map.updateSize();
      }

      function updateFilter(){
        if (!supportsFiltering) {
          return;
        }
        var filterType = document.getElementById('filterType').value;
        var filter = document.getElementById('filter').value;
        // by default, reset all filters
        var filterParams = {
          'FILTER': null,
          'CQL_FILTER': null,
          'FEATUREID': null
        };
        if (filter.replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '') != "") {
          if (filterType == "cql") {
            filterParams["CQL_FILTER"] = filter;
          }
          if (filterType == "ogc") {
            filterParams["FILTER"] = filter;
          }
          if (filterType == "fid")
            filterParams["FEATUREID"] = filter;
          }
          // merge the new filter definitions
          map.getLayers().forEach(function(lyr) {
            lyr.getSource().updateParams(filterParams);
          });
        }

        function resetFilter() {
          if (!supportsFiltering) {
            return;
          }
          document.getElementById('filter').value = "";
          updateFilter();
        }

        // shows/hide the control panel
        function toggleControlPanel(){
          var toolbar = document.getElementById("toolbar");
          if (toolbar.style.display == "none") {
            toolbar.style.display = "block";
          }
          else {
            toolbar.style.display = "none";
          }
          map.updateSize()
        }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>`
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried create layers in geoserver via sql server I founded through that the new Version of Geoserver is having problems whit sql server. My advice is to use PostgreSQL database with Postgis extension which is good option.

Answer (score 0):

In geoserver please go to `Layer preview` look for your layer and make click in `Open layers` if the layer preview shows the issue may be in your center coordinates.
[Check this image to see where to click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOMfq.png)

Also you may want to erase the STYLE line in your params (If you wont set an specific STYLE geoserver will use it's own so leave geoserver do all the work :p ) and the last comma (you should only use commas to separate elements, you don´t use a comma after the last element)

```
params: {'FORMAT': format,
               'VERSION': '1.1.1',  
            STYLES: '',
            LAYERS: 'MNC:LTE_130',
      }
```

it may be like

```
params: {'FORMAT': format,
               'VERSION': '1.1.1',  
            LAYERS: 'MNC:LTE_130'
      }
```

If the Layer preview works you can use the generated code to start from scratch, it's the easiest way :p

Let me know how it goes, if the layer preview doesn't work we can think in some workarounds

Regards

Comment: Hello , I tried your suggestion and still not working.
My layers doesn't appear when I click in 'openlayers', I just see a white box. 
What can you suggest to find a solution to this problem?
Thank you!

Comment: Yes, all the sample layers. :/

Comment: Then the problem is in your layers or in the projection, have you tried them in qgis or another gis?

Comment: Yes, I have tried with postgis and worked! With postgis I had to deal with shapefiles to import to the database and with microsoft sql server I don't need that. Would be much more easier with microsoft sql server however I cant get any output :/. 
I let my email address here if you prefer: amsss11@iscte-iul.pt